How to install finger print driver for the device "Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4" on Ubuntu 24.04?
I'm using a HP Pavilion laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 I'm unable to view the fingerprint option in the settings can please someone help me. I've already installed fprintd and libfprint-2-2
